# How do we have ${\mathbf {v} }^{\mathrm {T} }{\mathbf {v} }={\mathbf {v} }^{\mathrm {T} }Q^{\mathrm {T} }Q{\mathbf {v} }$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Overview), if a linear transformation, in matrix form $Q{\mathbf {v}}$, preserves vector lengths, then:

$${\displaystyle {\mathbf {v} }^{\mathrm {T} }{\mathbf {v} }=(Q{\mathbf {v} })^{\mathrm {T} }(Q{\mathbf {v} })={\mathbf {v} }^{\mathrm {T} }Q^{\mathrm {T} }Q{\mathbf {v} }.}$$

What happens to $Q^{\mathrm {T} }Q$?

Comment: It's the identity matrix

Comment: Are you saying $Q = I$, and there's no other $Q$?

Comment: $Q^TQ$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If $Q$ preserves vector lengths, then $Q$ is orthogonal, thus $Q^TQ=I.$

Comment: Can you give me an example? It'd be easier to see.

Comment: @J.Doe An example of $Q$ can just be the identity matrix, or if you want something less trivial, you can have rotational matrix as well

Answer (score 0):

To add some examples to Fred's answer you could for take matrices that realize reflections or rotations.

If one exchanges the rows of the identity matrix you get a transformation that preserves length:
$Q_1=\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}$

You can check that $Q_1 {Q_1}^T=I$ and for any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$ one gets $||Qv||=||v||$.

Another example is a 2D rotation with angle $\phi$ that is realized by the matrix

$Q_2=\begin{array}{rrrr}
cos \phi & -sin \phi  \\
sin \phi & cos \phi  \\
\end{array}$